# How to get mouseenter function to display data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a bar chart that I want to be able to hover over the bars and display some data on the top of the chart as text.

I don't want to use tooltips and when I change my text to a normal string like "boom" it will display that on mouse entry. However, it wont display the data.

I have the mouseenter and the function it calls in the code below. Basically I need a way for the mousenter to tell the function what the data it. For some reason it wont do that.

Ive tried useing .text(d3.select(this).text(d.data)) in the function.
I have also tried getting rid of the function and having it all as one code. Also did not work

```
.on("mouseenter", flash("mode0Danceability"))

function flash(name) {
  return function() {
    svg.append("text").attr({id: "fish"})
        .attr("class", "boom")
        .attr("x", 45)
        .attr("y", -33)
        .text(svg.html(d.mode0Danceability))
        .style("font", "20px sans-serif")
        .style("fill", "steelblue");
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best method IS to create a tooltip, just give it no borders and append it as a text to a particular location not as a div.